# Installing and running jekyll on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, sass, jekyll

I tried Github pages on Friday and found it great so decided to install Jekyll locally (Windows 10) so I could build and test offline.   After spending almost a day and trying multiple recipes (from theserverside.com, jekyllrb.com, etc) for how to install Jekyll I finally got `jekyll -v` to work.  (Note that the instructions I found weren't bad but probably just out of date.  People need to updates their blogs, or better people should stop changing how things are set up!)

However, now when I try to serve a test site I get a Segmentation fault (as below).  I have tried starting again from scratch several times and even strangely get different results but have never gotten as far as serving the site.

````bash
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x64-mingw-ucrt]```

$ jekyll -v
jekyll 4.2.2

$ jekyll new myblog

...

$ cd myblog

$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: e:/Work/tmp/Daily/blog/myblog/_config.yml
            Source: e:/Work/tmp/Daily/blog/myblog
       Destination: e:/Work/tmp/Daily/blog/myblog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0033 p:---- s:0182 e:000181 CFUNC  :compile_data_context
c:0032 p:0314 s:0177 e:000176 METHOD C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43
... 

[+576 more lines of backtrace and runtime info - available on request]
````

Thanks for any help you can give me to get Jekyll working.

BTW I don't like to complain but getting Ruby and Jekyll installed and running has been a royal pain. Maybe I have been spoilt with Go which literally took less than 10 minutes to install and have a running program (though calling C from Go (using CGO) took me a few hours to get working).  Moreover, if Jekyll was written in Go it would a simple matter of downloading a single `jekyll.exe` - ie a few minutes instead of **days** (or however long it takes to get this working).

**Update**: I have tried lots of things with varying results but I never get as far as Jekyll serving the site. I don't know enough about Ruby and/or understand what the error messages mean to try to fix these things so I have now taken to documenting exactly what I tried and the result.  Here are the last 4 things I tried and the result:

================================

1. Using Ruby 3.1.2.1 + Devkit (x64) and following instructions at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/ which run without error but then serving a test site has an error:

```
$ jekyll -v
jekyll 4.2.2

$ jekyll new myblog
...
New jekyll site installed in D:/myblog.

$ cd myblog

$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: D:/myblog/_config.yml
            Source: D:/myblog
       Destination: D:/myblog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 1.829 seconds.
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'D:/myblog'
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.2.2   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command
                     for any additional information or backtrace.
                    ------------------------------------------------
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require':
 cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:179:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:179:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:100:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
```

=======================================

2. Using Ruby 3.1.2-1 and following instructions at https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/jekyll-install-windows-example-blog-tutorial after a lot of trial and error I eventually got `jekyll serve` to run but it said "generating feed" then stopped and there was no server running at http://localhost:4000.

=======================================

3. Using Ruby 3.0.4-1 (x64) and following instructions at https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/jekyll-install-windows-example-blog-tutorial I get to the very end but when I try to serve the a test site I get:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: D:/myblog/_config.yml
            Source: D:/myblog
       Destination: D:/myblog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.758 seconds.
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'D:/myblog'
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.2.2   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command
                     for any additional information or backtrace.
                    ------------------------------------------------
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

===================================

4. Using Ruby 2.7.0.1 and following instructions at https://gist.github.com/arthurattwell/281a5e1888ffd89b08b4861a2e3c1b35 I get as far as the ridk install and which fails:

```
$ ridk install
...

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [1,2,3]

> sh -lc true
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed
Remove catgets to avoid conflicts while update  ...
> pacman -Rdd catgets libcatgets --noconfirm
error: target not found: catgets
error: target not found: libcatgets
MSYS2 system update (optional) part 1  ...
> pacman -Syu --needed --noconfirm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 mingw32 is up to date
 mingw64 is up to date
 ucrt64 is up to date
 clang32 is up to date
 clang64 is up to date
 msys is up to date
:: Starting core system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
MSYS2 system update (optional) succeeded
MSYS2 system update (optional) part 2 ...
> pacman -Su --needed --noconfirm
:: Starting core system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
MSYS2 system update (optional) succeeded
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...
> pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf autoconf2.13 autogen automake-wrapper automake1.10 automake1.11 automake1.12 automake1.13 automake1.14 automake1.15 automake1.6 automake1.7 automake1.8 automake1.9 diffutils file gawk grep libtool m4 make patch pkg-config sed texinfo texinfo-tex wget mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
error: target not found: automake1.10
error: target not found: automake1.6
error: target not found: automake1.7
error: target not found: automake1.8
error: target not found: automake1.9
warning: file-5.41-4 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gawk-5.1.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: grep-1~3.0-3 is up to date -- skipping
warning: sed-4.8-3 is up to date -- skipping
warning: wget-1.21.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain failed
Installation failed: pacman failed
```

Comment: you found some kind of bug in sassc gem, in line `status = Native.compile_data_context(data_context)`, you can submit an issue about it here: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues

Comment: Thanks I'll report the issue but how do I work-around the problem.  Maybe install an earlier version of Ruby or Jekyll?

Comment: try also this: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523 and you have another problem with webrick: `'require': cannot load such file -- webrick`, so check if `webrick` gem is installed and try to do these fixes on 2.7 ruby, not 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the instructions at [www.theserverside.com](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/jekyll-install-windows-example-blog-tutorial) and installing [Ruby 2.7.6](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/RubyInstaller-2.7.6-1/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.7.6-1-x64.exe)

Note that the install of Ruby messed with msys/mingw and now when I try to debug my Go program I get this error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../lib/libmsvcrt.a(/359): duplicate symbol reference: _unlock_file in both libgcc(.text) and libgcc(.data)
libgcc(.text): relocation target ___chkstk_ms not defined
libgcc(.text): relocation target atexit not defined
```

but I guess that is a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440626/installing-ruby-on-windows-breaks-go-debugging-due-to-msys-changes)