# Building with -race or CGO on Windows 10 fails with gcc duplicate symbol reference

Tags: go, mingw, msys2

**Edit:** I changed the title to better reflect what I am asking (was "Installing Ruby on Windows breaks Go debugging due to MSYS changes")

**Update:** I can now debug the code (after removing -race from my build configuration).  However, the question still remains how to get this to work when using race detection or CGO on Windows.

Since I installed Ruby on my Windows system (1,000 times more tedious to get working than Go :) I find I can't use the -race option or CGO.  I get errors irrespective of which version of gcc is used. I've tried Go 1.16.6 and 1.17.10 and gcc 5.1, 6.4, 8.1, 12.1.  Errors are like this:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../lib/libmsvcrt.a(/359): duplicate symbol reference: _unlock_file in both libgcc(.text) and libgcc(.data)
libgcc(.text): relocation target atexit not defined
```

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingwex.a(/6215): duplicate symbol reference: .refptr.__imp___mb_cur_max in both libgcc(.rdata$.refptr.__imp___mb_cur_max) and libgcc(.rdata$.refptr.__imp___mb_cur_max)
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmsvcrt.a(/47): duplicate symbol reference: _set_output_format in both libgcc(.text) and libgcc(.data)
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __imp___acrt_iob_func not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __imp___acrt_iob_func not defined
runtime/cgo(.text): relocation target __imp___acrt_iob_func not defined
libgcc(.rdata$.refptr.__imp___mb_cur_max): relocation target __mb_cur_max not defined
```

Comment: Something weird is in the PATH. MSYS2 bin directory should be first (preferably in the system-wide PATH, not user-specific). You can set it temporarily just for Go debugging...

Comment: MSYS2 has a Ruby package so you don't need to install "Ruby on Windows".  But if you really want to troubleshoot this, you might try running `env` from whatever environment you use to debug Go code and look for anything suspicious, or anything that changed when Ruby on Windows was installed.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat. After research I have seen mingw64 versions 6.4 and 8.1 recommended. So I installed them and put them first in the system (not user) PATH.  For 6.4 I get the last error as above (with different paths) and for 8.1 I get the top error above. [I did work out how to debug by removing -trace from build config.]

Comment: Thanks @David Grayson. I only want Ruby to run Jekyll (to test Github pages sites) and tried instructions from many diff places before I got it to work but never saw anything about MSYS2 Ruby package.  I'll try to find it.  BTW set/env revealed nothing but I did work out that the problem is triggered by -trace option.]

Comment: I didn't suggest installing a different MinGW version. I suggested adding `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the PATH.

Comment: Sorry @HolyBlackCat I should have mentioned that the MSYS2 bin directory was and is first in the system wide PATH.  I still get the issue, but have given up on it for now (using a Linux (WSL) that does not have the problem).

Comment: Ok. What I'm saying is, you have another compiler at `C:/TDM-GCC-64`, which interferes with MSYS2 (probably both are in the PATH).

Comment: Just came across a very similar issue—but when cross-compiling on Linux, then found [this comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47119#issuecomment-1144521605) seemingly made by the OP, and then tried the suggestion from Ian Lance Taylor there—using `-ldflags='-linkmode=external'`. That helped; [there is my commend on that](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47119#issuecomment-1296196452).